# How to find the mean value for $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am reading Courant's *Differential and Integral Calculus.* Here:

> Find the intermediate value $\xi $ of the mean value theorem for the following functions, and illustrate graphically:
>   (d) $1/(x^2+1)$

I am having a little bit of trouble to find $\xi$ in $1/(x^2+1)$. I did the following:

$$\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_2 - x_1}=-\frac{x_1+x_2}{\left(x_1^2+1\right) \left(x_2^2+1\right)}$$

So, there exists an $\xi\in [x_1,x_2]$ such that:

$$-\frac{x_1+x_2}{\left(x_1^2+1\right) \left(x_2^2+1\right)}=f'(\xi)$$

And then, obviously I could compute the derivative for $1/(x^2+1)$ which gives me $-\frac{2 x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}$ and attempt to solve:

$$-\frac{x_1+x_2}{\left(x_1^2+1\right) \left(x_2^2+1\right)}=-\frac{2 \xi}{\left(\xi^2+1\right)^2}$$

For $\xi$, but perhaps this would be *"too hard"* to do by hand, I suspect that there is something much simpler. I also guess that in general, any function which the derivative looks as the derivative of the function I provided, differentiating and solving for $\xi$ could be a nightmare. I have even tried on Mathematica and it gave me this:

[image]

I may be missing something truly silly here, Courant gives a very simple answer in his book.

Comment: No, I didn't do the wrong question. It's $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$, I have the book in my hands.

Comment: I'm sorry, the book has $\frac1{x^3+1}$. I can see it from the picture.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel This is a badly scanned image (I suppose), see [here (from my physical copy):](https://i.imgur.com/L3M6zTe.jpg) I must say I was also impressed because I also say a $3$ here and a $2$ in the book.

Comment: Right. Clarendon 2 really ticks OCR readers off.

Comment: Can you post the giant equation as an image instead? Mathematica supports exporting as image.

Comment: @qwr Solved. I knew it exports in image, but I thought it wouldn't lag too much. Silly me...

Comment: You can even post the image inline. Just the large equation was lagging my browser.

Comment: @qwr I guess its better this way. Because the image width is too big, I also don't think it will be useful for someone willing to answer. My intention was to point out that "even Mathematica is giving me crazy results".

Comment: There might be some interpretation issues, too. If $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}^+$, by *mean value* do we mean $\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ ? I guess we mean the $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(\xi)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, where the RHS is actually a mean value, but for the derivative.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I guess it's the last meaning you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you just leave this problem and go on. Why? In the section of answers to the book, answers are given for (a), (b), (c) and (e), but not for (d). This indicates that it will be horrible (practically impossible). We can just speculate if that was on purpose by Courant or not.

Just for the sake of clarification, the other answers to the exercises imply that one is indeed asking for $\xi$ such that
$$
f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}.
$$